# React-Router Link variables not converted to values

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm using the react-router Link component passing a variable using `/customers/${id}`. 
The link navigates to the right component, but instead of translating ${id} to its value, it passes it as text like this: '`/customers/$%7Bid%7D`'.

I'm using react-router 4.3.1

I'm learning React and am creating a simple master / detail webapp. 
I have successfully retrieved data from my API and rendered this as a list. I want to be able to click on the items in the list and navigate to a details component passing the unique ID as a parameter.

I've tried all sorts of things, but basically, I can't get `${}` to work no matter what I try. I have tried to google this problem but haven't found anyone with a similar problem. 
I've read a number of articles on how to set up routing using react-router v4 and are following these but encounter this issue.

If I try to pass in the link manually the route works fine and it navigates correctly to the details-component which renders the specific customer.

```
<Link to={'/customers/${this.props.item.Id}'}>{this.props.item.Name}</Link>
```

The Route looks like this:

```
<Route path='/customers/:Id' component={CustomerDetails} />
```

I expect the Link to generate the following URL: `/customers/3` but the actual result is `/customers/%7Bthis.props.item.Id%7D`
The variable name is correctly spelt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be using back ticks for string templating.

Instead of:

```
'/customers/${this.props.item.Id}'
```

use this:

```
`/customers/${this.props.item.Id}`
```

Read more about template literals here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals