# delete an item from a fetched data react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to delete an item from a fetched data from API, but whenever I try to press on delete button I got this error:

```
App.js:50          DELETE https://-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/%7Bid%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my code:

```js
const deleteProduct = async (id) => {
  await fetch(
    `https://upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/{id}`,
    { method: "DELETE" }
  );
  setProdcts(products.filter((product) => product.id !== id));
};

return(
  <div key={product.id}>
    <div>
      <div>
        <FaTimes
          onClick={() => onDelete(product.id)}
        />
        <p>{product. Price}</p>{" "}
      </div>
)
```

a photo of the error:

[image]

the code is in [sandbox code](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-wave-quiliu?file=/src/App.js)
So what happens after clicking on the delete sign it deleted all the items from the page, and then it re-loaded them.

I want to delete a specific item from the data.

Comment: Try changing `{id}` to `${id}`.

Comment: same error even after adding the $

Comment: Based on your image, your id is undefined and hence you are getting the error. You can check first there is a product and product.id and then load `<FaTimes .. />` like `product && product.id && <FaTimes onClick={() => onDelete(product.id)} />` . You can debug the product first and make sure that you receive the id.

Comment: so i have tried this one       {product && product.id && (
        <FaTimes onClick={() => onDelete(product.id)} />
      )} but it doesnt shown any Fatimes

Comment: Then I guess you are not getting the `product.id` , you need to do `console.log(product)` and check whether you have `id` inside it.

Comment: Or else update the data you get in `product` in the question.

Comment: it gives me `undefined` when consoling the id of the product

Comment: Yes that is the issue, so your product doesn't have id so the id to api url is passed as undefined. Please check why your product doesn't have id.

Comment: but i have checked it through postman and there is an `id`

Comment: Can you create working example in codesandbox and share it to check for more info. Because here issue is that the product is not having proper value is what the issue was.

Comment: i have added a sandbox

Comment: Your sandbox doesn't have any of your code. Can you check back?

Comment: could u please recheck?

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-wave-quiliu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you change from `id` to `_id`. Adding underscore before id. Like `product._id` .

Comment: Check this forked example https://codesandbox.io/s/new-cdn-64b59u . You need to make sure that you are making the name convention correctly. You have given `product.Price` but actual key is `product.price` . Its smaller case and not upper case. Same as mentioned for id as well.

Comment: im sorry but your sandbox is giving me an error `Failed to fetch`

Comment: it worked after adding `_id` to each `id` in the code

Comment: Hazal, Always make sure of of the correct property name you are using including lower and uppercase letters. Glad to help you. I have posted an answer, please feel free to accept and close it if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issue is that you are using the template literal string, so to include dynamic value, you need to add `${id}`

`https://upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}`

Another issue is that the error happen due to misspell of the `id`.

Based on the update in the question, actual property name is `_id` and **not** `id`.

**Forked example**

[image: Edit new-cdn-64b59u]

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `$` in your template literal, so the `id` variable can be substituted:

```
`https://upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}`
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: still same error

Comment: i have added $ but still not removing the item

Comment: it it really the same error? the path in the error `/products/%7Bid%7D` should have changed for something like `/products/42`

Comment: yes its same error, i have uploaded a photo of the error

Answer (score 0):

make sure to add "$" as the above answers and you should use `backticks` `` for string templating and not simple '' or double quotes "".

check the following issue on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53994397/8808725

Comment: i have added $ before id but still same issue
here is my updated code
`const deleteProduct = async (id) => {
    await fetch(
      `https://upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}`,
      { method: "DELETE" }
    );
    setProdcts(products.filter((product) => product.id !== id));
  }; `

Comment: const deleteProduct = async (id) => {     
    await fetch(\`upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}\`, { method: "DELETE" }).then(() => {      
        setProdcts(products.filter((product) => product.id !== id));   
      })     
    }; 
  }

copy past this code snippet, i added "\" to avoid code format

Comment: would u please edit ur answer by adding this code snippet? i couldn't understand it

Comment: ive got an error after copying and pasting ur answer
`Line 53:2:  Parsing error: 'return' outside of function`

Comment: delete the last "}"

const deleteProduct = async (id) => {     
    await fetch(\`upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}\`, { method: "DELETE" }).then(() => {      
        return setProducts(products.filter(product => product.id !== id));   
      })     
 };

Comment: same error again

Comment: would u please check the code on sandbox?
https://codesandbox.io/s/little-wave-quiliu?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Another response with a formated code for visibility

```
const deleteProduct = async (id) => {     
    await fetch(
       `upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/${id}`, 
       { method: "DELETE" }
    )
    .then(() => {      
       return setProducts(products.filter(product => product.id !== id))   
    })     
};
```

Comment: am getting this error `DELETE http://localhost:3000/upayments-studycase-api.herokuapp.com/api/products/undefined 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: try to console.log(id) before await fetch... line, to check if you send the valid value id to the function

Comment: Here the main issue is that the `product` doesn't have `id` property inside it. So only if OP provide enough info about this, it can be resolved.

Comment: @ManirajMurugan would you please check the code on sandbox?

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-wave-quiliu?file=/src/App.js